# AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to delete batches of entities of a single Kind from my datastore using the defined function  `findpins` below. The parameter `limit` tells the number of entities from the Kind `Pin` to delete.
In practice, `limit` will be just below 20000 to make the daily deletes free. I am doing a `keys_only` query to avoid reading each entity.

But in testing my code I get the following error.

> AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'delete'

**Update 0**
If, instead of `pin.delete()`, I use `print pin` I see two 80 character strings which I assume are 2 Keys. But I don't know how to use the Keys for deletion.

**Update 1**
If, instead of `keys_only=True`, I use `keys_only=False` I accomplish the delete. But then I have encountered a potential charge for a read which is costly. Is that correct?

How can I fix this?

If you see other issues with my strategy, please say so, too.

**Update 2**  My revised Python code based on @jccampanero's suggestion is promising but so far fails in `isinstance` because of its arguments `Model` and `Key`. First I got the error message `NameError: global name 'Model' is not defined`. But then when I replaced `Model` with `Pin` I get the error `NameError: global name 'Key' is not defined` and I cannot imagine what to replace `Key` with. I don't know what I'm doing with these new definitions, and am particularly uncomfortable with the params `**kwargs`. So I could really use some help here. Am I on the right track?

Python code (**editted with 2 new imports, 2 new def's and 1 new delete command**) :

```
import os
import pprint

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import datastore
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_rpc
def delete_async(models, **kwargs):
  if isinstance(models, (basestring, Model, Key)):
    models = [models]
  else:
    try:
      models = iter(models)
    except TypeError:
      models = [models]
  keys = [_coerce_to_key(v) for v in models]

  return datastore.DeleteAsync(keys, **kwargs)

def delete(models, **kwargs):
  delete_async(models, **kwargs).get_result()



class Pin(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()


def findpins(limit):
    pin_query = Pin.all(keys_only=True) 
    for pin in pin_query.run(limit=limit):
        # was: pin.delete()
        delete(pin)
findpins(2)
```

Comment: It might help if you had a [mre] which included your imports and such. It's not obvious (to me at least) what libraries you're using.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. `from google.appengine.ext import db` has been added.

Comment: I have never used this library, but according to its source code, please, consider use the `db` - `Pin` - [delete](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/db#delete) function. It takes as arguments the keys of the records you want to delete. You can only fetch the keys (`keys_only=True`) in your query. I hope it helps.

Comment: @zerowords Based on your edit, please, be aware that the class `Model` and the variable `Key` are both defined in the `db` module, please, search for them in the indicated source code. You can try importing them in your code, like `from db import Model, Key`. Perhaps even you can try of course `from db import *` but I do not know if importing all the symbols from the `db` module can be the cause of any problem. Probably you can try in your code `if isinstance(models, (basestring, db.Model, db.Key)):` as an alternative.

Comment: `db.Model` and `db.Key` worked. And I had to define `_coerce_to_key` which was also give at your suggested link. `_coerce_to_key` also required the fix to `db.Model` and `db.Key`. Btw, `from db import Model, Key` throws an error. I did not check that there was no Read operation, but I suspect there is none.

Comment: That is great @zerowords, I am happy to hear that it worked properly. Yes, the use of `_coerce_to_key` makes perfect sense. Have you tried `db.delete(pin)` in your code? I think it can work as well. I am sorry for the imports, as I told you, I haven't used the library, and probably python is complaining about some dependency or any related problem.

Comment: Yes, using `db.delete(pin)` works without the other changes. Answer the question.

Comment: That is great @zerowords, I am happy to hear that it worked properly. Thank you, I posted an answer with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code of the library, you can use the [`delete`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/db#delete) function for that purpose: it accepts the key of the record you want to delete.

Please, consider the following modification in your code (note the use of the aforementioned `db.delete` function):

```py
import os
import pprint

from google.appengine.ext import db
class Pin(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

def findpins(limit):
    pin_query = Pin.all(keys_only=True) 
    for pin in pin_query.run(limit=limit):
        db.delete(pin)
findpins(2)
```